# Can I wear my taweez necklace from when I was a baby?

Tags: tawiz

To clarify, I don’t believe in a necklace’s ability to protect me from evil, but my mom gave me the taweez necklace that was made for me as a baby. She said I was very sick and cried a lot, so in a moment of desperation, this was made for me. Would it be wrong for me to wear it, given I don’t believe in any ability for it to protect me? And would I be able to take it with me in the bathroom given it doesn’t have any visible Quranic ayaahs on it (it’s a tiny leather pouch on a string and looks pretty cool)?

Answer (score 1):

You do not assign any force to it now, but it was somehow considered as such when you were a baby, and you call it a tawiz.

Tawiz carrying the Name or the Word of Allah are commonly accepted (but we must be aware of the fact that it is not the tawiz that may protect us but Allah alone). Your necklace doesn't have this, so that it's not among what is considered permissible for this.

This [fatwa](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/19465/can-a-baby-have-a-taweez-around-its-neck/) considers it permissible to use a tawiz without words for a baby but recommends not to do so.

There's nothing speaking against it from the material (no gold). So, it seems not to be strictly haram to wear it but it is rather discouraged (makruh).

May Allah protect you.